# Que lenguaje usar para aplicaciones desktop responsive

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, response

Buenas tardes, tengo una aplicación escrita en java que necesito utilizar en diversos sistemas operativos, y a distintas resoluciones, el problema es que ni Swing ni JavaFX ofrecen un layout que me sirva (o no supe utilizarlos) para el diseño que necesito tener, y aun asi quedo con el inconveniente que conlleva el tamaño de fuente al pasar a las resoluciones altas que traen hoy en dia las notebook.
Intente dividir los paneles en mas subpaneles, a cada cual con un layout distinto intentando adecuarme, pero el diseño queda tosco, y al estirar el frame se ve como se distorciona todo, y algunos elementos en vez de acomodarse mejor simplemente generan espacios vacios entre ellos.

Un ejemplo de panel es este :
[image]

Entonces, lo que necesito saber es si hay algun framework que permita hacer estas cosas mas simples, o si me paso directamente a otro lenguaje, como unico requisito tengo los mencionados arriba (adaptable a las resoluciones, como si fuese una web app), y que se pueda manejar correctamente la transmision de paquetes UDP.